# How to dynamically generate attributes?

Tags: python, object, attributes, python-2.x

I was using the below python code:

```
class A(object):
   def __getattr__(self, name):
       print "__getattr__ : %s" % name
       setattr(self, name, A())
       print self.__dict__
       print getattr(self, name)

 x = A()
 x.a = 1 .  # Works fine.
 print x.a

 x.b.c = 2 # Throws error.
 print x.b.c
```

The last part throws the following error:

```
NoneType object has no attribute c.
```

Can anyone explain what the error is in the above code as `print self.__dict__` clearly shows that both `a` and `b` have been inserted into the object's dictionary.

My use case is to have an object for which attributes can be dynamically added as and when required. Like I should be able to use:

```
x = A()
x.a = 1
x.b.c = 2
x.d.e.f.g = 3
```

Also, is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Update: Found the error, `__getattr__` should return a value.

**Correct code**

```
class A(object):
   def __getattr__(self, name):
       print "__getattr__ : %s" % name
       x = A()
       setattr(self, name, x)
       print self.__dict__
       print getattr(self, name)
       return x # getattr(self, name)

 x = A()
 x.a = 1 .  # Works fine.
 print x.a

 x.b.c = 2 # Works fine.
 print x.b.c
```

Comment: `__getattr__` must return the value of the attribute (the newly created `A` object)

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks a lot, everything works fine now. I wasn't aware `__getattr__` should return something. Basically i went through this example: https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/04/12/getattr-setattr.html

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you check if the above is the correct way of writing the code as per python standards or some improvements are there?

Comment: Usually, you would here just do something like `a = A()`, then `setattr(self, name, a)` and finally `return a` which is more efficient but your code is ok.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @MichaelButscher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called when an attribute is requested for get but is not available from the asked object.

Assuming that `x` hasn't an `a`, a call like

`result = x.a`

is functionally equivalent to

`result = getattr(x, "a")`

which is functionally equivalent to

`result = type(x).__getattr__(x, "a")`

which is normally the same as

`result = x.__getattr__("a")`

Last two variants only differ if the `__getattr__` is bound to the object instead of the class ([which may not work](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup))

As you can see here, `__getattr__` should return the value that `a` is meant to have.

It can also set the attribute directly so that further get requests do not call `__getattr__` again but are handled by Python directly. It depends on the particular use case if this makes sense (in your use case it does).

`x.b.c = 2` translates here normally to something like

`setattr(x.__getattr__("b"), "c", 2)`

Again, `__getattr__` must return here the object on which attribute `c` is set.